# Amazon EC2 上で Liferay7 の Docker イメージが起動できない

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ec2

開発環境用にAmazon EC2を準備し、[Liferay公式:Dockerイメージから始める](https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/ja/getting-started/starting-with-a-docker-image.html)を参考にしてdockerからLiferayを起動しようとしたところ、途中で止まってしまいます。

```
> docker run -it -p 8080:8080 liferay/portal:7.3.1-ga2
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この状態以前にメモリが足りない状態だったので、swapを2GBに増やしたところ、画像の様に進みました。

しかし、これ以上進まなかったので、念のためEC2のボリュームを20GBまで上げて、拡張してみたのですが状況は変わりませんでした。

どうしたらこの先の以下メッセージのところまで進むでしょうか。

```
> Wait until you see org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [x] milliseconds to indicate startup completion.
```

ご存じの方いらっしゃったら教えて頂きたいです。よろしくお願いします。

**環境:**

・Amazon EC2 (t2.micro)
・Docker導入済み
・[Liferay公式](https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/ja/getting-started/starting-with-a-docker-image.html)からdockerイメージ取得済み
・swapを2GBに変更して拡張

**参考:**

2GBに変更
[EC2にSWAPが無い](http://www.hokahoka.net/ec2%E3%81%ABswap%E3%81%8C%E7%84%A1%E3%81%84.html)

拡張
[EBSボリュームサイズを拡張しようとしたところ、ディスク使用率が100%で拡張コマンドが実行できない](https://qiita.com/kusano00/items/672da530de9245ca7457)

Comment: スワップだけではなく実メモリのサイズや使用状況の情報もあった方がよいと思います。(例えば実メモリ 1GB にスワップ 2GB を追加しても焼け石に水です) / また、数字には必ず正しい単位を付ける習慣を付けることをお勧めします。1G → 1GB , 20G → 20GB

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。すみません。EC2を初めて触っていてメモリなどについても手探り状態なため、ネット上の知識を一先ず試すことをしていました。EC2のt2.microのメモリが元々1GBということを検索して知り、増設しました。焼石に水なのですね。どうしたら良いか分からないので調べます。そして、単位についてもご指摘ありがとうございます。気をつけます。後日、使用状況など確認し、追加しようと思います。

Comment: ググった感じ必要なスペックの規模感は[こんな感じ(pdf)](https://www.liferay.com/documents/10182/1645493/Liferay+Portal+EE+Reference+Architecture+%26+Hardware+Requirements/7f618f87-ca55-4e39-ba21-b3faadbca206)のようです。試してみるにしてもメモリは最低でも8GB(t2.largeなど)は必要に思われます。

Comment: >>DEWA Kazukiさま　詳しい資料まで添付頂いてありがとうございます。大変助かります。そもそもインスタンスの種類を変更しなければならなかったかもしれないですね。変更して実行したら、また結果を書こうと思います。

Answer (score 1):

編集のコメントをしていただいた方々、ありがとうございました。

インスタンスタイプ
・t2.medium（4GB）
・t2.large(8GB)
それぞれ試した結果、両方とも起動確認できました。

ただ、今回は更にdockerを途中で使うことにしましたので、
最初の質問環境とは若干違いますが、
いずれにしても、メモリー不足だったという分かりました。